# ng-show on the basis of model value of some other html element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I have a simple Angular Program in which the span must show only if the input value is 'Peter'. I was hoping that if I change input value then span must vanish, but when I am trying to change the value of input box, it is not allowing me do so. What is the issue due to which I am unable to change input value ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    <span ng-show="name='peter'">{{name}}</span>
    <script>
    //module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    //controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.name = "Peter";

    });
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `ng-show` to

```
<span ng-show="name.toLowerCase()==='peter'">{{name}}</span>
```

You are using assignment operator but you need to compare the values and also change the case of input value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    <span ng-show="name.toLowerCase()==='peter'">{{name}}</span>
    <script>
    //module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    //controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.name = "Peter";

    });
    </script> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: yes made error, should have used comparing operator "==" instead of assignment operator "=". My mistake ;(

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
   <input type="text" ng-model="name">
   <p ng-hide="name!== 'peter'">peter</p>
   <p ng-show="name!== 'peter'"></p>
   <script>
   //module declaration
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   //controller declaration
   app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){ 

});
</script>
```

Comment: Ha ha ... much simpler, but I did not meant that. This is workaround only to real concept ...